# How to keep Multibranch Pipeline job from cloning repo on master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Multibranch Pipeline job, pointing to a Bitbucket Server repository.

Before it executes anything on the Jenkinsfile, it always always does a full clone of the repository in a master node workspace.

It creates a new workspace, with a new clone of the repository, for every single branch.

Not only can this take significant time for some of the larger repositories, but it also is taking up a lot of space on the master node.

Is it possible do do any of the following:

1. Download (and execute) the Jenkinsfile without cloning the full repository
2. Clone the repository on another node other than master
3. Automatically remove the workspaces of auto-deleted jobs

Answer (score 0):

Found it really annoying as well. Apparently there is currently no workaround for this issue. To start the build Jenkins requires `Jenkinsfile` located in the repository so it fetch the full repo to find it. More information can be found here: [JENKINS-33273 Optimize Jenkinsfile loading and branch detection](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273).

The workaround for the master running out of HDD space is to delete repository copy after the job is done. Just append this snippet to your `Jenkinsfile`.

```
node('master') {
    stage 'Cleanup repository from master node'

    // Due to the MultiPipeLine problem with fetching full repository on the
    // master node we need to manually cleanup the workspace to prevent trashing
    // HDD with copies of the git repository
    def workspace = pwd()
    dir("${workspace}@script") {
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```